# Can java default library path simply be updated with Spring jars to avoid per project configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning Spring (for Java) and intend to be able to deploy multiple spring java mvc web projects to amazon AWS cloud servers.

Every spring tutorial I've seen includes the step of manually adding a bunch of spring jar files to the build path for each new project that is created.

Wouldn't there be a way to simply run a single script on my dev box (and another script on my server), which would simply retrieve a zipfile of all spring jars, and unpackage them into a standard java library path, so that I wouldn't have to worry about performing those steps for each new project I create?

My objective would be to create new spring projects that will have all spring dependancies resolved simply via the import statements.

Comment: Heard about Build Automation tools like, maven, gradle?

Answer (score 0):

It would not be very efficient.  Spring is a large suite with many jars, some of which your application will never need.

Even if you were to copy the Spring jars in this way, you would still need to specify which ones need to be packaged into the web applications that you want to deploy.  Adding them all would bloat the web application and may lead to higher AWS costs, and definitely lead to more maintenance cost when the application needs to be updated.

You might want to use a dependency management tool such as Maven to specify which jars you need for each project.  It is an upfront investment of a few minutes, but leads to clean and understandable project composition.